# How to create a JavaFX Image from an absolute path?

Tags: java, file, javafx, path

I have an instantiated `File` object. I know it contains a picture format. I don't know where on the system the file is placed, other than the methods of `File` available to me `getPath(), getAbsolutePath()` etc.

My question is: how can I instantiate a JavaFX `Image` object with the picture in my `File`?

Comment: See [`ImageIO.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-) and then [`SwingFXUtils.toFXImage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#toFXImage-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-).

Comment: Thank you very much :) You may post an answer to be accepted if you care, or I will do it myself later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`File` provides a method to retrieve the URL for the file and [the `Image` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-) expects a URL `String`.

```
Image imageForFile = new Image(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

Comment: Revisiting, I would prefer this solution as it does not involve memory copying as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the `javax.imageio.ImageIO` class ([ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)) and the `javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils` ([ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html)) can convert an "input" (i.e.: stream, file, URL) to a JavaFX image. Sample code (for `File`):

```
public static Image readImage(File file) {
    try {
        BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(file);
        return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bimg, null);
    }
    catch( IOException e ) {
        // do something, probably throw some kind of RuntimeException
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a solution, but for this case it involves an unnecessary memory copy. Please see fabian 's answer.