# javafx- difference between URI and absolutepath for a file

Tags: java, image, url, javafx, uri

I wanted to use an absolute path for Image URL in javafx . [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521378/how-to-create-a-javafx-image-from-an-absolute-path)  gives me a way to do that .

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty ("user.dir")+ "\\profile" + "\\chat3.png");
    System.out.println(file);
    System.out.println(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

These codes generate the following output:

> C:\Users\myUsername\Downloads\Compressed\15Dec\profile\chat3.png
>   file:/C:/Users/myUsername/Downloads/Compressed/15Dec/profile/chat3.png

what is the difference between these two lines?

Comment: One is a file path and the other is a URI? Not sure what the question means.

Answer (score 0):

The file.toURI() handles special character conversions, so in general calling file.toURI().toURL() is a better option since it will convert for example white spaces to %20 , For example if file name is "chat version 3.png" converts to :

file:/C:/Users/myUsername/Downloads/Compressed/15Dec/profile/chat%20version3.png

Answer (score 0):

Both lines point to the same resource file, they just use different syntaxes to do so.

> C:\Users\myUsername\Downloads\Compressed\15Dec\profile\chat3.png

Is an [MS-DOS style file path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#MS-DOS.2FMicrosoft_Windows_style).

It is a syntax used by Windows for identifying a file location.  Other operating systems will use a different format (for instance Unix uses forward slashes rather than back slashes).

> file:/C:/Users/myUsername/Downloads/Compressed/15Dec/profile/chat3.png

Is a [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).  It conforms to a [standard syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for identifying a resource.  The URI is a standard format and not specific to a given operating system (it will always use forward slashes).

In this case the URI type is a Uniform Resource Locator (URL) that identifies a resource accessed via the file protocol at the provided path.  The syntax for a URI is:

> scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]

To understand more, read the linked articles.